# Can we filter the values and put them into an array using VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Consider below Excel Sheet:

```
  Emp Id    Job Status
    741         P
    788         T
    111         T
    124         P
    136         P
```

I want an advanced VBScript Code which Can do such filtering in one shot,the way we did manually in Excel. After the filtering I want first column filtered values only to put into an Array.

**Code**

```
Dim IntRow1,Arr,Index
Index=0

Do while objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1) <> ""
    If objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,2) = "P" Then
        Arr(Index)=objSheet1.Cells(IntRow1,1)
        Index=Index+1
    End If
IntRow1=IntRow1=1
Loop
```

***UPDATE**

```
Option Explicit

Dim Dic, DicItems, Dickeys
Dim objExcel1
Dim strPathExcel1
Dim objSheet1, lastRow

Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
objExcel1.Workbooks.Open strPathExcel1
Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lastRow = 1
Do Until lastRow > objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1))
    Dic.Add objSheet1.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value, objSheet1.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
Loop

DicItems = Dic.Items
Dickeys = Dic.Keys

For lastRow = 0 To Dic.Count - 1
    If DicItems(lastRow) = "P" Then
        Dic.Remove (Dickeys(lastRow))
    End If
Next

DicItems = Dic.Items
'=======================
objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
objExcel1.Workbooks.Close
objExcel1.Application.Quit
'======================
```

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure to reduce sheet, code traffic. It's not advisable to interchange from sheet to code. We have provided you lots of code that shows taking a Range, Transpose it into an array, process array, then Transpose back into the Sheet Range. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Transpose functionality,Thus i asked you also in the previous post too.

Comment: @bonCodigo Can you just knock me in one thing,In what way calculation in array is highly preferable rather than the same in an Excel? What are the areas where I can think of such Transpose functionality?

Comment: [Transpose](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php) do you do any Google search?

Comment: Yes, I am doing Sir :-) Anyhow I need to clear the logic.If any doubt I will ask you.Please help me then:-)

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes I understood now,But now can I see a demo code on how to do filtering on Excel using VBS? If I can do that,then only filtered rows i will transpose to an 1D array.

Comment: I gone through from your link and http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/transpose-excel-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa/630 as well.  and the link  http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/vbscript_dictionary_object.htm

Comment: glad you do the search. Try out those and if got doubts do give a buzz.

Comment: you don't need `transpose` here ... check out `.AutoFilter` method, then `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` properties. Then you will be able to loop and load the values into an array. If you get stuck, do post your efforts and let us know.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Is the .AutoFilter an Range object?

Comment: `.AutoFilter` is a method you preform on a `Range` object. If you read about it it will be very easy to understand.

Comment: But I couldn't understand how should I pass values as an argument in VBScript?

Comment: @bonCodigo Can you review it please?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Can you check me updated code? Any more improvization you want to suggest here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please See my answer:

Option Explicit

```
 Dim Dic,DicItems,Dickeys
 Dim objExcel1
 Dim strPathExcel1
 Dim objSheet1,lastRow

 Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 strPathExcel1 = "D:\VA\CopyofGEWingtoWing_latest_dump_21112012.xls"
 objExcel1.Workbooks.open strPathExcel1
 Set objSheet1 = objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

 Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 lastRow=1
  Do Untill lastRow >         objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(objSheet1.Columns(1))

  Dic.Add objSheet1.Cells(lastRow,1).Value,objSheet1.Cells(lastRow,2).Value

 lastRow=lastRow+1
 Loop

DicItems=Dic.Items
Dickeys=Dic.Keys

 For lastRow=0 to Dic.Count -1

 If DicItems(lastRow)="P" Then

    Dic.Remove(Dickeys(lastRow))

 End If

  Next

 DicItems=Dic.Items

 '=======================
  objExcel1.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strPathExcel1
  objExcel1.Workbooks.close
  objExcel1.Application.Quit
 '======================
```

Comment: @bonCodigo can you review my code? If any improvement needed please advice!